# How can I save images with different name on different directory using PIL .save?

Tags: python, operating-system, python-imaging-library, os.path

I'm trynna get the train_img and ground truth img from directory './train_dataset/train_img_cropped' & './train_dataset/train_gt_cropped'. Next, I wanna save the both original image and flipped one with a '_0', '_1'tail on its name in directory './train_dataset/train_img_preprocessed' & './train_dataset/train_gt_preprocessed'. But there's an Error of changing names (file + "_0" or "_1") as an unknown file extension. Looks like somehow PIL recognizes _0, _1 as a extension. Is there anybody who can help me to save with changing the name?

```
import os
import os.path
import glob

from PIL import Image

def preprocess(img_path, save_path):
targetdir = img_path
files = os.listdir(targetdir)

format = [".png"]
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(targetdir):

    for file, i in files:
        if file.endswith(tuple(format)):
            image = Image.open(path + "/" + file)
            image.save(save_path + "/" + file)

            flippedImage = image.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
            flippedImage.save(save_path + "/" + file)

            print(file + " successfully flipped!")
        
        else:
            print(path)
            print("InValid", file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
train_img_cropped_path = './train_dataset/train_img_cropped'
train_img_preprocessed_path = './train_dataset/train_img_preprocessed'

train_gt_cropped_path = './train_dataset/train_gt_cropped'
train_gt_preprocessed_path = './train_dataset/train_gt_preprocessed'



preprocess(train_img_cropped_path, train_img_preprocessed_path)
preprocess(train_gt_cropped_path, train_gt_preprocessed_path)
```

Comment: If you had a filename  like "image.png" you now want to create a file named "image.png_0". The file extension is now "png_0" and it seems as if PIL doesn't recognize this as valid.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Also I'm already recognize it. So is there a way to solve this problem??

Comment: I figured it out by using os.path.splitext() to classify name and extensions. I added " _0" and "_1" to the name variables. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question, but why not save the image with a temporary name (something like a random alphanumeric string or uuid) and then use `os.rename` to change the name of the temp file with your desired name ending `_0` or `_1`.

Comment: Aha this could be the way. Thanks! If there's any othere good idea, pls feel free to give me haha

Comment: I figured it out by using os.path.splitext() to classify name and extensions. I added " _0" and "_1" to the name variables. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `os.path.splitext()` is what [Pillow uses to check for filename extensions](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/Image.py#L2244-L2252). So your best bid would be to use the same but if you prefer using temp names, you may use, `tempfile`, something like

```python
import os
import tempfile
temp_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), next(tempfile._get_candidate_names()) + ".png")
```